# SQL Server - write records to table only if they don't already exist - process flow upgrade needed

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

We have a C# program which, on a nightly basis, grabs data from thousands of websites and writes the results to one database table which contains 30 columns.  One of these columns (called TEXT) is a "catch-all" unstructured data column that can contain anything from a sentence of text from a website up to several paragraphs.  The nightly process produces approximately 2 million records.

It's currently set up such that the program writes all records to a "holding" table in a separate SQL Server instance.  Then our main table, which holds all 2 million records from the day before, is completely truncated.  Then the holding table sends all the data to the main table.

So we have a full delete and re-write of all records every day.  There MUST be a more efficient way to do this than this way.  I would like to skip the seemingly unnecessary middle steps and just have the program write directly to the main table.  But the only way I can imagine to do this is to append records if they don't already exist.  This seems daunting, as the columnar data is wildly inconsistent from record-to-record (as far as which may have data and which may not) but perhaps I'm overthinking it.

- Can I accomplish this using just one table?
- What would be the most    efficient way to ensure a record only gets
  written if it doesn't    already exist, given the structure (lack thereof) of the records?

I've read and considered the answer in this post: [How do I add a record only if it doesn't already exist in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730221/how-do-i-add-a-record-only-if-it-doesnt-already-exist-in-sql-server)  but I don't think the answer can serve our needs: It seems to only work with an explicit WHERE clause on one field, the value of which is manually indicated.

Comment: A two step process (using a staging table) is actually a good idea. Firstly: do you actually have a performance issue transferring 2 million records? Because a SQL statement truncating and loading 2 million records should take less than ten seconds. If you are transferring 2 million records row by row in a c# program, then that's your first problem

Comment: If you _do_ want to only add new records, and save the truncation step, then the only way to only add 'new' records is to work out what is new, and the only way to do that is to have some kind if identifying field that uniquely identifies a record. So what in your dataset uniquely identifies a record? Is it just the URL? Or is it the contents of your catch all field? If it's your catch all field then it's going to be computationally less intensive to just reload all data rather than compare huge text fields for differences.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I greatly appreciate the replies.  Ok, i would have absolutely no problem at all if the transfer took only 10 seconds!  It takes, are you ready for this... 15 HOURS.  So clearly the folks who set this up didn't know what they were doing then?  It's likely worth mentioning though that the transfer takes place from one Azure VM to another Azure VM, which I'm sure greatly increases the time needed.  The staging table, as mentioned in my post, is on a different SQL Server instance. That SQL Server is on a different VM.

Comment: OK, so firstly does the staging table _need_ to be on a separate instance? Can it be moved to the same instance? From what you've explained, there's no reason you can't just put the staged data into the same database in a different schema, then you can actually do a schema swap and the data just appears instantaneously. But first we need to understand why it was done that way in the first place.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid to answer your question in your 2nd post: the only unique identifier is a field called CaptureID which is unique for every single record.  So the CaptureID from night 2's records can't be compared to the CaptureID from night 1's records, as night 1's are all going to be different.  Further, many records won't have any data at all in the catch-all field.  It just depends on the source.  So the only way I could see it working is by comparing literally EVERY field of a given record, other than the CaptureID field.

Comment: OK that's good as we have established that an incremental load is not practical and a full load is the only option.

Comment: Regarding why it was done that way - the designer/builder explained it mainly as a security wall.  The VM with the staging table is not externally accessible.  It can only be accessed from within a vpn that links the two VM's together.  The main VM is accessible externally as it needs to be so our clients can query the main database.  All of our source-related data and configuration settings are housed on this private VM SQL Server with the staging table as well.  According to him this isolates us from security breaches reaching beyond the external VM.  Still not sure I fully understand though

Comment: So does it NEED to be a separate instance?  No, I really don't think so.

Comment: It seems to me that if this staging data is simply duplicated into the public VM anyway, there is no need for it to be housed on a private VM. If you can reconfigure your 'collector' to load data into the same database as the final database then you can probably save yourself 15 hours, not to mention network transfer costs (if there are any). Here's a link with some background on the 'schema swap' that I mentioned. This is just one way to do it. You issue those SQL commands and its just swaps the data in instantaneously, assuming your staging and final tables are identical.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks so much for your help - however there was no link in your post?

Comment: oops sorry. Here you go: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2 If you can establish that the data can be staged in the same database, and that the tables are (mostly) identical, then I can post some SQL code to help you.

Comment: That would be incredibly helpful.  The tables are almost identical.  One of the field names differs slightly between the two (same data), and the staging table lacks one field that the main table has, which is auto-populated with a default value.  Otherwise, identical.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm off to bed now but will post back in about 9 hours.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks so much.

Comment: While you rest, I'll be moving the main database from the VM to an Azure SQL Database, which I've been needing to do for a long time.

Comment: I've added an answer below but the devil is in the detail - feel free to ask for clarification as you come up against things

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- You have two tables in the same azure database
- The staging table is already populated and is called `stg.MyTable` (`stg` is a schema)
- The final table is `dbo.MyTable`
- Fields are pretty similiar

Here are two ways to get data across:

A. TRUNCATE/INSERT

This method actually uses some CPU and disk to copy the data over but it preserves all of the tables indexes, keys pk's etc, and doesn't require the tables to be identical

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Field1, Field2, Field3)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM stg.MyTable

-- Optional step: clear the staging to free up space
TRUNCATE TABLE stg.MyTable
```

B. Schema swap

This is one of many methods that effectively rotates the table under your nose. Many different people appear to have come up with this in isolation. It has the following constraints:

- it requires tables to be identical.
- very fiddly if you have triggers or Foreign Keys

From your description, I don't see any reason the tables can't be identical

This is based on the excellent description (including diagram!) found at 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/149123/

In short you:

1. Load data into stg.Table (clearing it first)
2. Switch the live table into a holding area to preserve it:

   `alter schema holding transfer dbo.Table`
3. Switch the staging table into live - you now have your data loaded

   `alter schema dbo transfer stg.Table`
4. Switch the table out of holding into stage ready to accept data

   `alter schema stg transfer holding.Table`

Note that this breaks things like triggers and foreign keys so you need to consider those.

Just remember that ongoing, you now need to make column and index changes to *both* tables. The other alternative is to keep a index and PK script off to the side and reapply it

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks so much for this detail.  The schema swap is definitely what I'm after so I will work toward getting the table to be identical.  We'll also definitely want to recreate our indexes, so I can easily script those out and add them to the full script.  I'll be working on this all day tomorrow so I may very well have additional questions for you.  I'm now turning in for sleep and will chat tomorrow.  Thanks again!

Comment: I've altered my answer to provide and overview of the three schema approach which you'll need to preserve indexes and PK's

Comment: Wonderful Nick, thank you.  Due to other items falling onto my plate, I have not yet had a chance to try this out.  I should be doing so later today or on Monday.  I'll be back in touch to report on it or ask any other questions.  Thanks!